# Circuit from NI DAQ 6001 to push button

Tags: circuit-design, button, daq

[image]

I need to design a circuit with a NI DAQ 6001 and 3 push buttons. I don't know any design software, so I just drew by hand. I can give an explanation for you to understand.

Pins 1, 2, and 3 are programmed to be digital output pins which give a 5 V output and pins 4, 5, and 6 are programmed to be digital inputs.

I need a 5 V signal to the push button which will then be read by the NI DAQ. For this I wired from DO Pin 1 to the push button and then from the push button to DI Pin 6. Similarily DO Pin 2 -> push button -> DI Pin 5 and DO Pin 3 -> push button -> DI Pin 4. On receiving 5 V at the DI terminals, the rest will be done by the software. There is already a pull-down resistor in the NI USB 6001, so I haven't used any. Is this circuit correct?

Answer (score 0):

This will work as you have proposed.
Note that since you always want 5 volts on one side of the switches, you can tie them together and use just one DO pin to supply them.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4tpoG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You don't even need a D-out pin to supply the 5 volts, because there is a dedicated +5 volt pin on the DAQ module that you can use.

I've added a schematic, mostly to show you that this is a handy feature you can use on this site.  Experiment with it and you will find it useful when you post your next question.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will do that.